# Display a map in a Windows Form app

Tags: c#, winforms, maps

I built a Winform app several months ago that schedules appointments for repair techs. I'd like to update the app by adding a map for the customer's address on the customer form, and then print that map on the report the techs take when they leave the office.

I've been looking around but I haven't found a good solution for this yet.

I currently have an address for the customer.  What I'd like to do is submit the address to one of the popular online map sites and get a minimap of the locale.  I can *almost* do this with Google maps using their embedded link feature.  I can get the following HTML after adding an address to their website:

```
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
   marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
   src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;g=1193+Presque+Isle+Dr,+Port+Charlotte,+FL+33952&amp;s=AARTsJqsWtjYwJ7ucpVS6UU2EInkRk6JLA&amp;ll=27.012108,-82.087955&amp;spn=0.005735,0.006437&amp;z=16&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

My first plan was to simply parse this HTML and insert whichever customer's address was needed in place this address, then show the result in a browser object on the form.  However, if I change the address in the above iframe Google gives me a "Your client does not have permission to get URL ..." message.

I have no preference on which map service I ultimately use, the important thing is that the solution can't have an associated expenses and its usable from Windows forms.

Anyone got an ideas/recommendations/resources on how to tackle this?

**Results**:

I ended up using the control found [here](http://www.codeplex.com/VEarthControl).  I find it an "okay" solution... it's tedious to get working as the code does not work as-is.  I'm pretty stunned to find that none of the popular map APIs support winforms.

Comment: Just an update... I haven't tried this control but it seems promising: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Google Maps and Live Maps have a public api.

Since you are doing winforms I'd probably use live maps.

http://dev.live.com/VirtualEarth/

There are a few examples on CodePlex.

http://codeplex.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Virtual%20Earth

Comment: None of the above solutions were very good, but since I used a control I found on codeplex I gave this answer the checkmark. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is [some example code](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2008/07/virtual-earth-and-google-maps-tiled-map.html) for developing a map viewer control (NB: I doubt this is strictly within their licence)

Otherwise, depending on your budget, you could use the [MapPoint ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc905749.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the value inside the src="" as the location for a WebBrowser control directly, without the IFRAME.

OR

Build a minimal html document wrapping the IFRAME,  write it out to a MemoryStream, re-seek it back to the start, and use the MemoryStream to set the WebBrowser control's DocumentStream property.

PW